# python connect_cloudwatch different region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to connect and dynamically get ALL metrics for ALL services available in AWS CloudWatch in a particular AWS Region:

```
try:
    print "Connecting to region %s" % (args.region)
    conn = boto.connect_cloudwatch()
    #conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region(args.region)
    print "Retrieving all CloudWatch metrics"
    metrics = conn.list_metrics()
    print "Collected %d metrics" % (len(metrics))
except boto.exception.BotoServerError, error:
    print "Failed to connect to AWS\n  ->%s" % (error)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Unfortunately `boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region(args.region)` give me only EC2 metrics from a region, and I couldn't figure out from the documentation how to specify a region to `conn = boto.connect_cloudwatch()`. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the Cloudwatch region in the `.boto` config file. For example:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = <your aws access key>
aws_secret_access_key = <your aws secret access key>

[Boto]
cloudwatch_region_name = us-west-2
cloudwatch_region_endpoint = monitoring.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

The above will connect you to us-west-2 when you run:

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_cloudwatch()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the best shot that I can take so far. Thanks, @Rico! I'll give it a try and will follow up on this post. Do you know of any dynamic solution to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The code you show above looks fine.  The `list_metrics` method will return all of the metrics which actually have data associated with them in the current account.  If you are only seeing EC2 metrics then that means that your account only has EC2 data collected in CloudWatch for that region.

Comment: I guess I'm looking to an answer of how to provide a different region. Is it possible to do it programmatically for `boto.connect_cloudwatch()`? What would be the code sample to do it?

Comment: Well, you can construct your own RegionInfo object and pass it to the ``boto.connect_cloudwatch()`` method but I'm curious about why you would want to do that.  I think it's much easier to use ``connect_to_region()``.

Answer (score 0):

`boto.connect_cloudwatch()` will do exactly the same as `boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_region('eu-west-1')` but without asking for the region. The region is used from the configuration in `~/.boto`. The common way to specify the region is to use `connect_region('myregion')` or just set it in the configuration if you do not work across multiple regions.

So if you don't find your metrics in the connection object created by `boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_region('eu-west-1')` you won't find it in the other one. Both cases creates a `boto.ec2.cloudwatch.CloudWatchConnection` object. ([Boto documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/boto.html#boto.connect_cloudwatch))

As far as I understand the documentation boto currently does not support other metrics than EC2-metrics.